# How to get JSON data from localhost in Android Studio (RESTful API)

Tags: java, android, json, api, rest

So i've followed some tutorial on YT on how to get JSON object and JSON array of objects from website using URL and it worked. The code is below. Now, i've tried doing the exact same thing with URL of my localhost database, but it didn't work. I didn't get any errors or anything, and i have no idea what is the problem. I'm trying to do some RESTful API, in which the code in java is creating table with data in database, and it works perfectly, it's just that i cannot connect android app to it.

```
package com.example.motto_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup RG;
    RadioButton bA, bB, bC, bD;
    TextView tA, tB, tC, tD, tQ;
    Button bN;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //assigning variables to objects in layout
        RG = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        bA = findViewById(R.id.answerAButton);
        bB = findViewById(R.id.answerBButton);
        bC = findViewById(R.id.answerCButton);
        bD = findViewById(R.id.answerDButton);

        tA = findViewById(R.id.answerAText);
        tB = findViewById(R.id.answerBText);
        tC = findViewById(R.id.answerCText);
        tD = findViewById(R.id.answerDText);

        tQ = findViewById(R.id.textQuestion);

        bN = findViewById(R.id.NextButton);



        //on-click listeners
        bN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                String url ="http://localhost:8080/quiz";


                JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        String question = "";

                        try {
                            JSONObject cityInfo = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            question = cityInfo.getString("question");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Question: " + question, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                queue.add(request);
            }
        });

        bA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "AAA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        bB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "BBB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        bC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CCC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        bD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DDD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now i just want to add that the only thing that i've changed from the original code from YT is URL and variable names. The code worked perfectly with standard URL. Here is how my localhost looks: [http://localhost:8080/quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SELO.png)

Comment: "Here is how my localhost looks" is funny (since nobody else can see it).

Answer (score 0):

By localhost do you mean the PC you're programming on, or the android device itself?

In the case you mean the Android device itself-  you would never use a RESTful service here.  You'd just make direct DB calls.

In the case you meant your PC-  that isn't localhost.  Not to the device.  You need to use the actual IP of the device.  Even if you're using an emulator, the emulator thinks its a separate machine and has its own IP address-  localhost would only go to the emulator.  And if its an actual device and not an emulator, you need to have your WIFI set up to allow traffic to that port (assuming your PC is on the same wifi network as your device.  If not, its even more complicated).

Comment: by localhost i meant the PC, since that's where database is runnig. As for using ip, do you mean that instead of using URL variable in code i have give it id of my PC? or my database in postgre?

Comment: You can't reach your PC using localhost.  Localhost always refers to the machine itself.  If you're using an emulator, you can use 10.0. 2.2 instead of localhost.  If you're using a real device, you need to use the actual IP number of your PC.  And if using a real device you need to ensure your wifi network is set up to allow traffic to your PC from other devices.